# finding local time and date from internet using command line

Tags: time, date

How can I get time and date from internet using command line like when I type curl ipinfo.io it shows me my ip. Is there something for time and date as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access APIs thorough for fetching some data through curl like for extracting the date and time over the internet from command line I curled an api mentioned below:

http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/:area/:location[/:region]

the command i ran was:
curl "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Karachi.txt"

The APIs are available at the link: http://worldtimeapi.org/

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

solution that does not require `jq` (not pre-packed) :

```
curl -s "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip" | cut -f12,13,14 -d ':' | cut -c 2-
```

if you don't necessarily need internet time then it would be :

```
echo $(date)
```

also with date you can pretty it up to the format you want :

```
echo $(date --rfc-3339=seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

[worldtimeapi.org](http://worldtimeapi.org):

```
curl "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip" | jq
```

Comment: how do i know which websites would work for curl on command line ?

Comment: you just have to know ...